# Cosmos db Table API SSIS component or ODBC connector?

Tags: ssis, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have a Cosmos DB Table API entity and i can't figure out how to export the data whether I use SSIS or an ODBC connector. I want to export into a datawarehouse and connect to tables in the on prem DW. I see one can setup a linked server but that uses a DSN and I can't get the ODBC conn to connect to the table API.

Comment: What is your destination ?

Comment: The destination is an on prem DW in SQL 2017

Comment: does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/odbc-driver

Comment: thanks but no. That ODBC driver only works with the SQL API. I can't find anything to work with the Table API.